# PostgreSQL query (EF + Devart) fails in application, but works in PgAdmin

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, devart

I have a problem with one of my SQL (PostgreSQL) queries generated by Entity Framework with Devart connector. After exactly 60 seconds (every time), I get an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlException:
>   Read failure ---> System.IO.IOException: Read failure --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond
>         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags) [0x00000] in :0
>         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Common.au.a (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.aa.d (System.Exception A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Common.z.d (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Common.ae.a (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.x.c (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.x.f () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ai.a (Boolean A_0, Boolean A_1, Char A_2, Boolean A_3) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ai.b (Boolean A_0, Boolean A_1) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ai.c (Boolean A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ae.b (Boolean A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ae.g (Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ac A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ae.b (Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ac A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ac.af () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlDataReader.f (Int32 A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand entityCommand,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in :0
>         at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[LisExaminationRequest]
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext context,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection
>   parameterValues) [0x00000] in :0
>       [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlException:
>   Read failure ---> System.IO.IOException: Read failure --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond
>         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags) [0x00000] in :0
>         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Common.au.a (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.aa.d (System.Exception A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Common.z.d (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Common.ae.a (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.x.c (System.Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Int32 A_2) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.x.f () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ai.a (Boolean A_0, Boolean A_1, Char A_2, Boolean A_3) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ai.b (Boolean A_0, Boolean A_1) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ai.c (Boolean A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ae.b (Boolean A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ae.g (Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ac A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ae.b (Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ac A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.ac.af () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlDataReader.f (Int32 A_0) [0x00000] in :0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand entityCommand,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in :0
>         at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[LisExaminationRequest]
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext context,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection
>   parameterValues) [0x00000] in :0

I tried to experiment with timeouts in connection string, but it didn't help. This is the content of `DbContext.DataBase.Connection.ConnectionString`

```
User Id=myuser;Host=myhost;Port=5432;Database=mydatabase;Unicode=True;Connection Timeout=300;Default Command Timeout=300;SSLMode=Disable;
```

This query (generated by `EF`) is very large. It has over 6500 lines of code (the `query` not the result) and consists of numerous `UNION` statements.

The same query ran manually in `PgAdmin` executed in about 120s.

Comment: The connection is not set up properly.  Do check if you can connect from that server using those credentials.

Comment: @JakubKania Connection is set up ok. Other queries work fine.

Comment: In that case try manually timeouting the connection like `SELECT pg_sleep(120)` and see it the error is the same.

Comment: @JakubKania pg_sleep called using `DbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand()` (the same context I use for EF) worked fine. After I changed timeout to default in connection string - it failed with normal message 'Error: 08006: Server did not respond within the specified timeout interval'.

Comment: So if the query timeout error is different I still believe the problematic query is not run with the same connection.

Comment: @JakubKania It surely is. The connection for pg_sleep was taken from exactly the same EF DbContext object that I use one line below for the problematic query.

Answer (score 0):

> Default Command Timeout=300;

Could you please [send us](http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) a small test project with the corresponding DDL/DML script for reproducing the issue with ignoring the Default Command Timeout connection string parameter?

Comment: I'm unable to extract a small project in this case. However, the problem has been solved. Database health was in bad shape. After a backup, and a restore (the same server) everything went back to normal. Still, it's strange the query worked fine in PgAdmin and failed in application. I can send you the generated SQL, and related LINQ code if you wish.